# Woocommerce: show custom product data in checkout review order and invoice

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, orders

The price of the products is calculated in the shop based on a field "Length" which the user submits on the product page. As this length is important information I want to show the submitted length also in the cart, review order in checkout and invoices.

I have succesfully added the field to the cart, but how can I add it to the cart items in the review order and invoices? (Or even in every product mention in the whole process). Is there a filter or action I can use? And how? I could not find any?

I have the following (relevant) code:

```
// Get custom field value Length, calculate new item price, save it as custom cart item data
add_filter('woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'add_custom_field_data', 20, 2 );
function add_custom_field_data( $cart_item_data, $product_id ){
    if (! isset($_POST['length']))
        return $cart_item_data;

    $length = (float) sanitize_text_field( $_POST['length'] );
    if( empty($length) )
        return $cart_item_data;

    $product    = wc_get_product($product_id); // The WC_Product Object
    $base_price = (float) $product->get_regular_price(); // Product reg price

    // New price calculation
    $new_price = (($base_price * $length)/1000)+1.90;

    // Set the custom amount in cart object
    $cart_item_data['custom_data']['extra_charge'] = (float) $length;
    $cart_item_data['custom_data']['new_price'] = (float) $new_price;
    $cart_item_data['custom_data']['unique_key'] = md5( microtime() . rand() ); // Make each item unique

    return $cart_item_data;
}

// Set the new calculated cart item price
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'new_price_add_length', 20, 1 );
function new_price_add_length( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 )
        return;

    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        if( isset($cart_item['custom_data']['new_price']) )
            $cart_item['data']->set_price( (float) $cart_item['custom_data']['new_price'] );
    }
}

//Add length to product in cart
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_cart_item_name', 'wmw_display_length', 20  );
function wmw_display_length( $cart_item ) {
    if( isset($cart_item['custom_data']['extra_charge']) ) {
        $length = $cart_item['custom_data']['extra_charge'];
        echo '<dl class="variation"><dt class="variation-Length">Length(mm):</dt><dd class="variation-Length"><p>' . $cart_item['custom_data']['extra_charge'] . '</dd></dl>';
    }
}
```

Any ideas how to get this data also in the other locations/screens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

**For testing purpose only**, as you didn't provide the code that displays a "length" input field in single product pages, I use the following function:

```php
// FOR testing: Display length field in single product pages
add_action('woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'testing_custom_product_input_field', 5 );
function testing_custom_product_input_field() {
    
    woocommerce_form_field('length', array(
        'class'       => array( 'form-row-left') ,
        'label'       => __('Length(mm)', 'woocommerce' ),
        'placeholder' => __('Define the required Length (in mm)') ,
        'required'    => true,
    ) , '');
}
```

Then I have simplified and make changes to your provided code, so now the "length" is displayed in cart mini-cart and checkout pages.
Use the following code replacement:

```php
// Get custom field value Length, calculate new item price, save it as custom cart item data
add_filter('woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'add_custom_cart_item_data', 20, 2 );
function add_custom_cart_item_data( $cart_item_data, $product_id ){
    if ( isset($_POST['length']) && ! empty($_POST['length']) ) {
        $product = wc_get_product($product_id); // Get WC_Product Object
        $length  = (float) sanitize_text_field( $_POST['length'] );
        $price   = ( floatval($product->get_regular_price()) * $length / 1000 ) + 1.90;  // New price calculation

        $cart_item_data['custom_data']['length'] = $length;
        $cart_item_data['custom_data']['price']  = $price;
        $cart_item_data['custom_data']['unique_key'] = md5( microtime() . rand() ); // Make each item unique
    }
    return $cart_item_data;
}


// Display custom cart item data in mini cart, Cart and Checkout pages
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', 'display_custom_cart_item_data', 20, 2 );
function display_custom_cart_item_data( $cart_data, $cart_item ) {
    if( isset($cart_item['custom_data']['length']) ) {
        $cart_data[] = array(
            'key'   => __('Length(mm)', 'woocommerce'),
            'value' => $cart_item['custom_data']['length'],
        );
    }
    return $cart_data;
}


// Set the new calculated cart item price
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'new_price_add_length', 20, 1 );
function new_price_add_length( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 )
        return;

    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        if( isset($cart_item['custom_data']['price']) )
            $cart_item['data']->set_price($cart_item['custom_data']['price']);
    }
}
```

Add the following missing code, that handles mini-cart displayed custom price:

```php
// Handle mini cart displayed price
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', 'display_new_price_add_length', 20, 2 );
function display_new_price_add_length( $price_html, $cart_item ) {

    if( isset($cart_item['custom_data']['price']) ) {
        $args = array( 'price' => floatval($cart_item['custom_data']['price']) ); 

        if ( WC()->cart->display_prices_including_tax() ) {
            $product_price = wc_get_price_including_tax( $cart_item['data'], $args );
        } else {
            $product_price = wc_get_price_excluding_tax( $cart_item['data'], $args );
        }
        return wc_price( $product_price );
    }
    return $price_html;
}
```

To finish, add the following to display your "Length" on customer orders, admin orders and email notifications and invoices:

```php
// Save and display the Length (custom order item metadata)
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', 'save_order_item_custom_meta_data', 10, 4 );
function save_order_item_custom_meta_data( $item, $cart_item_key, $values, $order ) {
    if( isset($values['custom_data']['length']) ) {
        $item->update_meta_data( 'length', $values['custom_data']['length'] ); 
    }
}

// Add readable "meta key" label name replacement
add_filter('woocommerce_order_item_display_meta_key', 'filter_wc_order_item_display_meta_key', 10, 3 );
function filter_wc_order_item_display_meta_key( $display_key, $meta, $item ) {
    if( $item->get_type() === 'line_item' && $meta->key === 'length' ) {
        $display_key = __('Length(mm)', 'woocommerce' );
    }
    return $display_key;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and work.

---

**Checkout page:**

[image]

---

**Customer order:**

[image]

---

**Admin order:**

[image]

---

**Email notification:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it looks great! However I can not get it to work. That is, I don't see Length appearing in the order review part or somewehere else. Also not in the database with a completed order. I would expect it in the order_itemmeta. So as it is not in the database, maybe the problem is somewhere else?

Comment: I have updated my answer code and everything is tested and work.